# Cannot access to Django admin page with valid username and password in Chrome. But in firefox, it works fine

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, firefox

During an Udemy lecture, I tried to access the Django admin page, but I couldn't enter the page with valid userID and password in chrome. Also, the stylesheet is not applied to the index page. However, in FireFox, it perfectly works. Is there any special thing I should do for Chrome?
Please let me know what I do for Chrome. 
Here are my codes which are setting.py and views.py
Thanks in advance

in views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Topic, Webpage

def index(request):
    webpages_list = AccessRecord.objects.order_by('date')
    date_dict = {'access_records': webpages_list}
    # my_dict = {'insert_me' : "I am from views.py in first_app"}
    # return render(request, 'first_app/index.html', context=my_dict)
    return render(request, 'first_app/index.html', context=date_dict)
```

in setting.py

```py
"""
Django settings for first_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'a=@bj_n7#+65&sop)#o=5nm^po8j35d@c)e#ca)85#i(_wjdz6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first_app'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'first_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'first_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

Comment: We don't need your source code if it's everything fine in Firefox. Press Ctrl+Shift+Del and try with deleting "Cached images and files". Restart your django development server and try.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! but still cannot access admin page with a valid user ID and password. Do you know why?

Comment: Dunno, try in incognito (private) mode, or with starting chrome like `google-chrome --disable-extensions --disable-plugins`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is likely due to the `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` in your `settings.py`. If set to `True` and you access the app with http and localhost (127.0.0.1), Chrome-based browsers will not let you authenticate, whereas Firefox will.